# RouterLink working on NavbarComponent but not working on HomeComponent

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I cannot user RouterLink with HomeComponent however it is accessible with NavbarComponent. I have the same component code with the 2 (generate from `ng g component`) with different template view. Code for app.module.ts is here

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { RoutingModule } from './routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And my RoutingModule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const router = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(router) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})

export class RoutingModule { }
```

Is it something wrong with them? or is it because of the component itself? here is my component code for HomeComponent and it is exact same with NavbarComponent but different names.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Edit: this is the line Angular2 render.

`<a _ngcontent-myo-3="" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl" routerlink="about" ng-reflect-router-link="about" ng-reflect-href="/about" href="/about">Find Out More</a>`

This is what I have in the backend:

`<a routerLink="about" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl">Find Out More</a>`

And this is not a link (not clickable)

Comment: `AppComponent` is `NavbarComponent`? If not - it lacks in your `routing` file.

Comment: what do you mean by you 'cannot user RouterLink with HomeComponent' ? Do you have an error or something like that ?

Comment: `<a routerLink="about" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl">Find Out More</a>` doesn't get recognized as a link. The `NavbarComponent` is just a navbar, it is not a site to render so I didn't give access to `RoutingModel`. The `NavbarComponent` uses the `RoutingModel` but the `RoutingModel` doesn't use `NavbarComponent`. Is it the wrong logic? I'm new to angular, but it works fine until I add `HomeComponent` to use `RouterLink`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry my bad, it was something to do with the z-index that makes it not clickable as a link. The RouterLink works fine.